# Calculating Probability

Tags: probability

Hi looking for advice on how to calculate the probability of the following.

If someone has a 4% chance of catching a disease (so 4 people out of 100)

Then if they caught the disease they have a 15% chance of it not showing up with tests, so 15 out of 100 who have caught the disease won't be diagnosed with the disease.

What is the overall probability of this happening combined?

Comment: one approach you could take is to draw it out using a [probability tree diagram](http://www.mathsisfun.com/data/probability-tree-diagrams.html).

Answer (score 1):

We use one of the basic rules of probability

$P(AB) = P(A|B)P(B)$

where here $B$ is the event "caught the disease" and $A$ is the event "test comes back negative".

It's simply a matter of substitution from there.